# how to unit test a function which called CoroutineScope.launch

Tags: unit-testing, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

Given `suspend fun`:

```
private suspend fun fun1(arugment1: String): NetworkResult<Unit>
```

how the unit test the following fun2 and fun3

Q1: 
the function which called suspend fun:

```
fun fun2(argument1: String) {
    launch {
        CustomService().fun1(argument1))
                .onSuccessEmpty { _: Int, _: Headers ->
                    Log.d("TEST", "onSuccessEmpty")
                }
                .onSuccess { _: Int, _: Headers, _: Unit ->
                    Log.d("TEST", "onSuccess")
                }.onError {
                    Log.d("TEST", "onError $it")
                }
    }
}
```

Q2:

```
fun fun2(argument1: String) {
        runBlocking {
            CustomService().fun1(argument1))
                    .onSuccessEmpty { _: Int, _: Headers ->
                        Log.d("TEST", "onSuccessEmpty")
                    }
                    .onSuccess { _: Int, _: Headers, _: Unit ->
                        Log.d("TEST", "onSuccess")
                    }.onError {
                        Log.d("TEST", "onError $it")
                    }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Since we never want to have top-level functions in our tests suspend, we always run them in a blocking manner. So the correct way would be `Q2`. Since `Q1` uses `launch`, it'd just fire-and-forget. (I might've misunderstood your question, but I believe you're asking which of the two ways is better.)